AWS CloudHSM Cluster Initialization Issues: CSR Not Visible
I am trying to initialize an AWS CloudHSM cluster, which requires downloading a CSR and creating a certificate from it. The process is explained here: AWS CloudHSM Guide.
My problem is that I don't see the CSR in the web UI, nor can I get it from the AWS CLI. Here is my Terraform script for creating the cluster:
resource "aws_cloudhsm_v2_cluster" "cloudhsm_v2_cluster" {
 hsm_type = "hsm1.medium"
 subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.subnet_cloudhsm_1.id, aws_subnet.subnet_cloudhsm_2.id]
}

resource "aws_cloudhsm_v2_hsm" "cloudhsm_v2_hsm_1" {
 cluster_id = aws_cloudhsm_v2_cluster.cloudhsm_v2_cluster.cluster_id
 subnet_id = aws_subnet.subnet_cloudhsm_1.id
 ip_address = "10.0.1.100"
}

resource "aws_cloudhsm_v2_hsm" "cloudhsm_v2_hsm_2" {
 cluster_id = aws_cloudhsm_v2_cluster.cloudhsm_v2_cluster.cluster_id
 subnet_id = aws_subnet.subnet_cloudhsm_2.id
 ip_address = "10.0.2.100"
}

I noticed that when I create only one HSM in the cluster, there is a CSR request to download. Any idea what could be the problem?

The note in the terraform docs says this: To initialize cluster, you have to add an HSM instance to the cluster, then sign CSR and upload it.. So maybe add one, do the CSR signing, upload it, and try with a second instance?
